# Помогите, пожалуйста, доделать код

Tags: smarty, инспекция-кода

Наизобретал, по моему мнению, полную чушь, но это единственное до чего додумался. Проблема в том, что это работает, но решение ужасно каменное, 
хотелось бы завести что-то типа счетчика или условие, которое автоматически будет приписывать каждому последующему шагу цифры, помогите разобрать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{if $category->level<3}

    ....

{else}  

    {if $category->path|count==3}

        <h2>{$category->path[$category->path|count-2]->expanded_title}</h2>

            {$first_category = $category->path[$category->path|count-2]}
                ...
            {categories_sub_two categories=$first_category->subcategories}
    {/if}

    {if $category->path|count==4}

        <h2>{$category->path[$category->path|count-3]->expanded_title}</h2>

            {$first_category = $category->path[$category->path|count-3]}
                ...
            {categories_sub_two categories=$first_category->subcategories}
    {/if}

    {if $category->path|count==5}

        <h2>{$category->path[$category->path|count-4]->expanded_title}</h2>

            {$first_category = $category->path[$category->path|count-4]}
                ...
            {categories_sub_two categories=$first_category->subcategories}
    {/if}

{/if}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь вы уже точно знаете значение `$category->path|count`:

```
{if $category->path|count==3}
```

Сами же проверяли, что оно равно `3`. Зачем вы высчитываете его еще раз здесь, непонятно:

```
<h2>{$category->path[$category->path|count-2]->expanded_title}</h2>
```

---

Во всех подобных вызовах и проверках у вас всегда результатом вычисления выражения `$category->path|count - X` будет единица. Да и если рассуждать логически, если вам нужна первая категория, то зачем заниматься лишними вычислениями?

Можно же сделать так:

```
{if $category->level < 3}
    ....
{else}
    {$first_category = $category->path[1]}
    <h2>{$first_category->expanded_title}</h2>
        ...
    {$categories_sub_two categories=$first_category->subcategories}
{/if}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает верно, за исключением того что все подкатегории раскрыты, а планировалось раскрывать при нажатии, но ваше решение, просто находка, спасибо вам огромное !!!